# scan and split a string

Tags: ruby

How can I get the results from both scan and split form a string - positive and negative matches? Equivalent to

```
def scan_and_split(string, regexp)
  string.split(regexp).zip(string.scan(regexp))
end

scan_and_split("{T}: Add {W} or {U} to your mana pool. Adarkar Wastes deals 1 damage to you.", /\{[^ ]+\}/)
```

Expected output:

```
[["", "{T}"], [": Add ", "{W}"], [" or ", "{U}"], [" to your mana pool. Adarkar Wastes deals 1 damage to you.", nil]]
```

Comment: Please show us the output you're expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `split` with captures.

```
"ababab".split(/(a)/)
# => ["", "a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b"]

"{T}: Add {W} or {U} to your mana pool. Adarkar Wastes deals 1 damage to you.".split(/(\{[^ ]+\})/)
# => ["", "{T}", ": Add ", "{W}", " or ", "{U}", " to your mana pool. Adarkar Wastes deals 1 damage to you."]
```

If you want a subarray for each `split`/`match`, then apply `each_slice(2).to_a` to the result.

```
"ababab".split(/(a)/).each_slice(2).to_a
# => [["", "a"], ["b", "a"], ["b", "a"], ["b"]]

"{T}: Add {W} or {U} to your mana pool. Adarkar Wastes deals 1 damage to you.".split(/(\{[^ ]+\})/).each_slice(2).to_a
# => [["", "{T}"], [": Add ", "{W}"], [" or ", "{U}"], [" to your mana pool. Adarkar Wastes deals 1 damage to you."]]
```